# C# debugging and deferred execution with yield return

Tags: c#

I have the following code from which i want to return one FileInfo object at a time, but i got the error message shown:

```
public static FileInfo GetTextFile(string path, string pattern, SearchOption searchoption)
    {

        DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        var files = dirs.EnumerateFiles(pattern, searchoption);//Getfiles is eager

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
             return file;
        }


    }
```

> 'FileEnumarater.GetTextFile(string, string, SearchOption)': not all code paths return a value

I did some research online and saw that i need to use "yield return" for this to work, so i changed the code to this and the error went away:

```
 public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetTextFile(string path, string pattern, SearchOption searchoption)
    {

        DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        var files = dirs.EnumerateFiles(pattern, searchoption);//Getfiles is eager

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            yield return file;
        }


    }
```

However, when i debug im expecting to step through this code one line at a time, but this is not happening. From my calling code below, the debugger is not going into the static class but straight over the highlighted code.

What else would i need to change for this to happen? I read that i need to force the code to execute by adding `.ToList()` which i did in my first screenshot but it did not help.

Perhaps ive placed it in the wrong place?

Here is my calling code which is just  the main method in a console application. The debugger steps over the highlighed line:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"G:\General\";
        var x = FileEnumarater.GetTextFile(path, "cmb*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);//add ToList to force evaluation
    }
```

Comment: Use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`. If you want to process one file at a time you should also use a loop where you process it: 
`foreach(var file in x){ ... }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for the reply. I have tried that with and without ToList() with the same result. Its not stepping in to the static class. As for the for each, i have it in the first screenshot.cheers

Comment: Your code seems to be an exact replica of this mehtod: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx Any reason for not using the built mehtod in directly?

Comment: Instead of iterating over `files` in `GetTextFile` you might as well just return it directly e.g. `return dirs.GetFiles(pattern, searchOption);`

Comment: Please don't include code as images. It's text, so include it as such.

Comment: @nicK: I've edited my comment above, `x` is just the "query", you need to do something with it, f.e. use a `foreach`-loop or `ToList`/`ToArray`/`First`,... to process it

Comment: @Lee will that not return an IEnumerable of all the files as opposed to one at a time?

Comment: @mortb that is but a coincidence :) im learning C# and did parts of this off pseudocode and a tutorial video. Im currently learning about static classes, and the goal is to have a general purpose one i can use for different applications. Hence i want the code separate

Comment: `GetFiles` already returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`, all you're doing is wrapping the returned array into a lazy sequence and then failing to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the sequence returned from `GetTextFile`. You can use `ToList` to force the iteration but you need to use it on the returned sequence, not the one returned from `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` i.e.

```
var x = FileEnumerator.GetTextFile(path, "*list.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

If you want to step through the control flow from within your own code you can iterate over the result sequence manually using `foreach`:

```
foreach(FileInfo fi in FileEnumerator.GetTextFile(path, "*list.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
{
    //process result
}
```

Note that `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` already returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` so you can just return it directly instead of converting it into a lazy sequence:

```
DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(path);
return dirs.GetFiles(pattern, searchOption);
```

If you want the results to be retrieved lazily you should use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` which is eager:

```
return dirs.EnumerateFiles(pattern, searchOption);
```

Comment: thanks, your first suggestion worked ! by adding the ToList to the calling code i was able to step into the static class. Thanks also for the tips..still learning.

Comment: Question my understanding of yield is that on debugging, you should see the cursor go back to the calling code, then return to the function that has the yield statement and continue on the next line. Why i'm in not seeing  that here?

Comment: @Nick - You should see that happen, how many results are in the result sequence?

Comment: I have 14 files in the result. when i add the ToList() as per your first code snippet above, i can see the cursor looping in the foreach loop, but it doesnt return to the caller. When i remove the ToList() in the caller, it steps right over the line in the caller without going into the static class.

Comment: @Nick - Well the caller is `Enumerable.ToList` so you'll need to enable stepping into the .Net source to see control pass to it. If you remove the call to `ToList` the iterator won't be invoked. If you want to keep the evaluation in your own code I suggest you manually iterate over the results with a `foreach` loop instead of using `ToList`.

Comment: Lee, you're right. When i remove the ToList() and print the results to the console, i can see it do it one line at a time albeit really fast. With the ToList() all lines are dumped on the screen at once. :)  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have a return value for all code paths because in the case when files is an empty array the return statement inside the foreach loop is never reached. You should treat the case when files is an empty array. By the way, your code always returns the first item in the "files" array. Is this your intention?